# (Android - Google Maps) Why polyline automatically making a closed figure

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I've been developing a map based app. In that I'm showing bus routes with the help of Polylines. Everything works fine as you can see in this image:

[image: First start]

But when I restart the app or revisit map activity, the polyline automatically connects the last and very first points (co-ordinates),thus making a closed figure.

[image: Revisit]

So is there any way by which I can stop the map from doing this?

#### Source code for map fragment

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

GoogleMap gmaps;
ArrayList<LatLng>coo = ProcessLatLng.getCoordinates(); //Getting co-ordinates into Array List

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
    prepareMap();
    return v;
}

private void prepareMap() {
    int i;
    if(gmaps == null)
        gmaps = ((com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    
    if(gmaps != null){
        PolylineOptions pop= new PolylineOptions();
        
        pop.width(5).color(Color.BLUE);
        
        for(i=0;i<coo.size();i++){
            pop.add(coo.get(i));
        }
                
        gmaps.addPolyline(pop);
        
        gmaps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coo.get(0)).title("Start"));
        gmaps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coo.get(coo.size()-1)).title("End"));
    
        gmaps.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.846785, 80.945591), 13));
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm not wrong, seems like same points are being added again, like this

The first time

(P1) **----** (P2) **----** (P3)

Second time

(P1) **----** (P2) **----** **(P3) ---- (P1)** **----** (P2) **----** (P3)

Try moving ProcessLatLng.getCoordinates() method to prepareMap method

Try getting polyline instance, and remove before fragment gone

```
Polyline mPolyline;
private void prepareMap() {
    ....
    ArrayList<LatLng> coo = ProcessLatLng.getCoordinates();

    ....
    mPolyline = gmaps.addPolyline(pop)
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion didn't work well but can you please provide some code for your second suggestion i.e. to remove polyline before fragment gone .

Suppose I'm having the polyline instance then how can I remove before map fragment is gone ?

Comment: I'm sure this, same points are being added one time more when map fragment showed. How you adding this fragment ? Is it in tabs ?

Comment: I checked in logcat, size of arraylist is increasing in the multiple of three i.e. same points are added. Even after calling " ProcessLatLng.getCoordinates() " inside prepareMap() function , same points are added

Comment: And I'm adding fragment in a separate activity.

Comment: Problem solved. Whenever i called getCoordinate method , it has been returning the same object of arraylist. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in how you code/set your Polyline. You can check here in this [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#code_samples) on how to use [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline).

To create a Polyline, first create a [`PolylineOptions`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions) object and add points to it. To add points to a PolylineOptions object, call `PolylineOptions.add()`. Notice that this method takes a variable number of parameters so you are able to add multiple points at a time (you can also call P`olylineOptions.addAll(Iterable<LatLng>)` if the points are already in a list).

You can then add the polyline to a map by calling `GoogleMap.addPolyline(PolylineOptions)`. The method returns a Polyline object with which you can alter the polyline at a later time.

Also check this [tutorial](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/07/draw-polyline-in-google-map-version-2.html) on how to use Polyline.

Comment: Still the output is same